# usage of "is" and "do"

Tags: usage

Why do you say, "A bus doesn't travel on water"  but you then say, "Garbage collection isn't a profession."  What are the rules for when to use "do" (doesn't) and when to use "is" (isn't)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer for the verbs on their own.  For verb phrases, that can become pretty complicated and seems to be beyond what you are asking.

The verb **is** usually acts to declare existence or (perhaps partial) equivalence:

- They said it wasn't there, but it is!
- He is just like his father.

The verb **do** usually specifies an action.

- He did it!
- I do pottery; my girlfriend does calligraphy.

Thus:

- A bus doesn't travel on water. [action]
- Garbage collection isn't a profession. [equivalence]
- The bus is traveling on water! [sigh, why I'm avoiding verb phrases  One could argue that "traveling on water" is a state of being, but I don't want to go there.]

Answer (score 1):

In Early Modern English, all verbs formed negatives by simply postposing "not":

> A coach goes not on water.
>
> Waste collection is not a profession.

In modern English, only auxiliaries (have, be, can, may, will, etc) form it in this way:

> I will not (won't) go.
>
> You can not (cannot/can't) go.
>
> He has not (hasn't) gone.

If there is no auxiliary, then *except for 'be' and sometimes 'have'*, you need to add the otherwise optional auxiliary 'do'.

So

> A bus travels on water = A bus does travel on water.

In the positive, the "do/does" is optional, and we only use it for contrast or emphasis; but in the negative

> A bus does not travel on water.

it is required.

The exception is "be":

> Garbage collection is a profession.
>
> Garbed collection is not (isn't) a profession.

In most varieties of English "doesn't be" is not grammatical.

The other partial exception is "have":

When it is an auxiliary itself, it cannot take "do":

> I have seen him.
>
> I haven't seen him (not "I don't have seen him").

When it is a full verb, both are possible:

> I have a car.

In the negative:

> I haven't a car.

or

> I don't have a car.

Many people would regard the first form as old-fashioned, especially American speakers. It's more common in British English, but even here, it is usually augmented by "got": "I haven't got a car".